# Need help for shifting a vector via array function on Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I need to shift elements of an (mx1) vector up by n rows. Last 3 cells become "0" (zero) instead of corresponding. I shared the task and my code below. I'de glad for further help.

[image: task]

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, nr As Integer, b() As Variant
    
nr = rng.Rows.Count
ReDim b(nr, 1) As Variant
    
    For i = 1 To n
        b(i, 1) = rng.Cells(i + n, 1)
    Next i
    For i = n + 1 To nr
        b(i, 1) = rng.Cells(i - n, 1)
    Next i

    ShiftVector = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(b())
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As close as possible to your code:

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Long)
    Dim i As Long, nr As Long, b() As Variant
    
    nr = rng.Rows.Count
    ReDim b(nr, 1) As Variant
    
    For i = 1 To n
        b(nr - n + i, 1) = rng.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
    For i = n + 1 To nr
        b(i - n, 1) = rng.Cells(i, 1)
    Next i

    ShiftVector = b()
    
End Function
```

**Further hints**

Assuming the above question is an exercise, you might consider the above code as learning chance and compare it to your original code. Generally I'd prefer @ScottCraner 's approach looping through a 2-dimensional array which isn't as *time consuming* as looping through a range by means of VBA, at least for greater data sets.

It's better to declare counters for such data as `Long` instead of `Integer` as today's range rows (1048576, earlier 65k) exceed the Integer data limit (-32,768 to 32,767) by far.

You don't need to transpose the `b` array as it's already 2 dimensional and can be inserted as vertical data set.

**Suggestion for improvement**

You can assign a whole data set to a 2-dim (1-based) array, e.g. as follows

```
    Dim tmp As Variant
    tmp = rng.Value
```

By changing the range offset you can shift up the main part of data automatically (preserving the same range size):

```
    tmp = rng.Offset(n).Value
```

This allows you to re-enter only `n` "wrap around" data to the bottom of the prefilled `tmp` array:

**Example function**

```
Function SV(rng As Range, n As Long)
'a) get main part (starting n rows higher)
    Dim tmp As Variant
    tmp = rng.Offset(n)       ' shift up vertically (by n rows)
'b) get "wrap around" part of n first rows
    Dim wrap
    wrap = rng.Resize(n, 1)    ' assign to temporary array
'c) enter "wrap around" values to n bottom rows
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        tmp(UBound(tmp) - n + i, 1) = wrap(i, 1)
    Next i
'c) return rearranged array as function result
    SV = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand my mistake and practise further hints!

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but you need a separate counter for the output in `b`.  I also prefer to make the output a 2D array and avoid the `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()`

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As range, n As Integer)
    If rng.Count < n Then Exit Function
    
  
    Dim rngArr() As Variant
    rngArr = rng.Value
    
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(rngArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = n + 1 To UBound(rngArr, 1)
        b(j, 1) = rngArr(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    For i = 1 To n
        b(j, 1) = rngArr(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    
    
    ShiftVector = b
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Posted my answer intentionally sticking close to OP (exercise?) roughly the same minute; of course I'd prefer your approach profiting from the additional 2-dim array.

Comment: FYI Might be interested in late edit: I shortened array code to a single loop with `n=3` iterations only. @Scott-Craner